# jquery ajaxForm retrieving fields inside hidden div

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

How i can stop jquery ajaxForm to retrieving fields inside hidden div ?

is this possible ajaxForm will not post hidden div fields ?

Comment: please give us some code and more info... is ajaxForm a plugin?

Comment: only "disabled" elements can be stopped during submit.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of hidden is that it's not visible but it is being submitted. If you don't want a field to be submitted then add disabled="disabled" to it.